# Possible reasons why an on.('click') function isn't firing?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(function() {
  $("#edit_current_pick").on('click', function() {
    alert("I see you. I click you. You worked before, why aren't you working now!?");
     // ... do stuff
  });
});

<span id="edit_current_pick" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span> Edit Current Seleciton </span>
```

This was working fine. Can't for the life of me understand why it suddenly stopped working. No naming conflicts, no console js errors.

I see the button. I click the button. Nothing fires. What can it be?

Comment: You haven't properly implemented event delegation, so this would need to be inside document.ready. Is it?

Comment: Have you made any changes AT ALL? Do you have any errors in your console?

Comment: Did you install any new plugins that have a pop up blocker in them?

Comment: No plugins installed. Code wrapped in doc.ready shorthand. Everything was working fine earlier today. No console errors. (except see comments in @isherwood) answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try either

```
$(function() { // document.ready shorthand
    $("#edit_current_pick").on('click', function() {
        // ... do stuff
    });
});
```

or

```
$(document).on('click', '#edit_current_pick', function() {...})
```

To explain further, there's no difference between `on('click')` and just `click()` unless you delegate to something that exists at the time the page loads.

Comment: What do you take of this: `Uncaught TypeError: Object #edit_current_pick has no method 'apply'`

Comment: The uncaught type error is produced by `$(document).on('click', '#edit_current_pick'), function()  {  alert('...'); }` and I have all of my code wrapped in doc.ready shorthand. Any idea what's happening here?

Comment: The function is supposed to be the 3rd argument. I just edited the answer to fix the typo. jQuery saw the 2nd argument and assumed it was supposed to be a function (because usually the last argument to `on` is a function`. The error about 'apply' is because it was trying to "call" `'#edit_current_pick'`.